# Is any Perl like translation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any inbuilt function for each string translation to another string in JavaScript?

For example

```
A <=> T

G <=> C
```

My input string like this `AAATATATTGC` I want to convert all `A to T` `T to A` `C to G` `G to C`. I want to output is `TTTATATAACG`.

In Perl, for this kind of situation easily do it.

```
my $s = "AAATATATTGC";  
$s =~tr/ATGC/TACG/;
```

I got the result.

Like perl, is any possible way for to do it in JavaScript.?

Comment: *is any possible way for to do it in javascript?* Yes, you can use the `translate` function. Unfortunately, you'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: actually you don't have to write the function yourself, if you finangle a Map()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with callback.

```js
// An object to use as replacement
var replacement = {
    A: 'T',
    T: 'A',
    C: 'G',
    G: 'C'
};

// Match a single upperCase character from given characters
var result = 'AAATATATTGC'.replace(/[ATCG]/g, function(_) {
    return replacement[_]; // Use the value of the key as replacement
});

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: `/[ATCG]/` character class will be better than alternation

Comment: @vp_arth Right. Updated answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation using a new [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) construct to avoid a hand-coded callback, which can be more reusable and composable than tying a function to a closured variable:

```
// replacements:
var reps= new Map([
    ['A','T'],
    ['T','A'],
    ['C','G'],
    ['G','C']
]);

var result = 'AAATATATTGC'.replace(/[ATCG]/g, reps.get.bind(reps));
// == "TTTATATAACG"
```

Maps are also more broadly useful as a look up table pattern because `0`, `"0"`, and `[0]` can all be distinct lookup keys...